# Получаю ошибку в Facebook Graph API Explorer...v2.9

Tags: php, permissions, facebook-graph-api

Это ошибка появляется, когда я пытаюсь отослать уведомление:

> {\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#200) Requires extended permission: manage_notifications\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":200

Comment: Please translate your question into Russian or move it to intl. SO.

Comment: Maybe you need to ask this question on English version of this site?